TimeoutError at /studentupdtpwd
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/studentupdtpwd
Django Version: 5.0
Exception Type: TimeoutError
settings.py:
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@amil.com'  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword' 
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = 860  

While sending email from a Django application using send_mail or EmailMessage sometimes it is working fine but sometimes getting TIME OUT ERROR for same logic.I also created another app and updated settings.py new generated password.

Your email_host_user should be EMAIL_HOST_USER =myemail@gmail.com
